# Grails Eclipse plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I've seen various posts on SO criticising the Eclipse Grails plugin, and am wondering if anyone has found a way to work productively with Grails within Eclipse?

I had a look at the [Grails plugin page](http://www.grails.org/Eclipse+IDE+Integration), and the information there doesn't look very promising, particularly the conflicting advice regarding the 'Disable Groovy Compiler Generating Class Files' setting.

Comment: You should turn this into a community wiki.   The answers to this question will continually change as new versions of IDEs and Grails come out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Original answer (left so people's votes aren't misrepresented):

Current IDE status (as of Mar '09) for Grails dev:

1. IntelliJ Idea still the best, but costly
2. NetBeans 6.5 is MUCH better than 6.1, but released before v1.1, unsure what the 1.1 changes may have done to this.
3. Eclipse is still far behind.  However, SpringSource is a major player in Eclipse, and they now own GOne, the main developers of Groovy/Grails.  This is supposed to have the effect of speeding Eclipse plug-in development, but no results so far.

It's now Dec '10, and things have changed (but not too much):

1. IntelliJ Idea is still the best, but only marginally so, and expensive.
2. Eclipse now has the STS (since Spring is a major developer), with a lot better Grails integration than before, especially for new projects.  If you're using Mavenized Grails... you may still want to stick with IntelliJ.
3. NetBeans 6.9.1 is out, but its Grails support is stagnant since 6.5.  It's now the bottom of the pack.

And now it's Feb '15, almost 6 years after the original question.  Much has changed, but much remains the same:

1. IntelliJ is still the best, and by a growing margin.  Grails 3 (due out next month) will actually allow development using the Community (Free) edition of IntelliJ
2. GGTS (The Eclipse package created by VMWare) has never really caught up, and will only get further behind now, as Pivotal has ceased its sponsorship of the Groovy/Grails team, and will probably also no longer drive GGTS development.
3. Seriously, does anyone still use NetBeans?  Ok, I see they still support Grails, but I don't really have any idea how good that support is.   Everyone I know... EVERYONE... uses IntelliJ.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! What exactly does v1.1 refer to, the version of the NetBeans grails plugin? Is this plugin bundled with NB by default or do you need to install it seperately?

Comment: Grails v1.1 just came out three days ago.

Comment: From this discussion, it looks like NetBeans 6.7 will have Grails v1.1 support: http://www.nabble.com/Groovy-Grails---NetBeans-6.7-M2-td22204718.html

Comment: FYI, Community Edition of IDEA supports Groovy and as best I can tell from the documentation Grails. So the fact that is expensive hardly matters now in this case (since Community Edition is free).

Comment: My information was that the community edition, while it may support the Groovy language, did NOT give the Grails framework integration in the free release.   If someone can put up a link that shows that's changed, I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 18):

The Grails Eclipse Tooling available in STS is now becoming mature.  I'd recommend trying this if you are still looking for a good way to develop Grails apps in Eclipse.

http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration

Comment: I wish I could give this another 5 votes so that the most correct answer (which now this one is) would be seen by others more easily.

Comment: @Esko I've updated my answer to include updated versions of the 3 IDEs.  Hopefully, this will appease, since I don't think the OP looks at this anymore, and didn't make it a wiki as I suggested.

Comment: This URL has gone private.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi That's unfortunate. Looks like you can still access the page through the wiki-style link: https://grails.org/wiki/version/STS%20Integration/7

Answer (score 4):

I used to be a die-hard Eclipse fan (wouldn't even imagine that I would work on any IDE other than Eclipse). But, I had to ultimately quit Eclipse in favor of either vi or IntelliJ IDEA after getting frustrated for couple of months.

But that was almost a year back. Haven't tried it again. I have high hopes from SpringSource to improve Eclipse tooling.

Answer (score 2):

prefer NOT to use STS - a custom Eclipse IDE for Grails. Looking to see if there is still a Grails plugin for Eclipse that would work. Using multiple projects that do not load in STS

Comment: STS is NOT a custom Eclipse for Grails.  It's Eclipse with a package of plugins pre-installed to work well with Spring's products, including Grails, but also including tcServer, Spring 3, Roo, etc.

Comment: Also, if your projects are unrelated and use different technologies, I'd suggest NOT putting them in the same Eclipse workspace.  Just start with another vanilla install (or with your common plugins) and then install the plugins you need for that set of related projects.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting with the NetBeans 6.7 release candidate after reading over the Eclipse documentation.  So far it is a pretty nice way to work with Grails.  You do have to configure your own hotkeys and such so that running your tests can be done in 2 key strokes.

I am having trouble with some of the claimed enhancements.  My code completion isn't working on my own methods, that's the single most annoying thing so far (at least, that isn't just a consequence of me being used to statically typed Java).  I need t figure out how to execute just a single test etc.

As someone that used NetBeans 7 and 8 years ago, I like what I see a lot better now.  I ran screaming to Eclipse back in 03, but Netbeans seems to have matured quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I installed STS as a plugin into my Helios Java EE install. Have mostly been using it for a sample Grails project as I learned Grails, but seems to work fairly well. Definitely Groovy support in Eclipse has improved dramatically in the last year.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using NetBeans 6.7 for Groovy/Grails development or TextMate (Mac only).  NetBeans 6.7 works great and should be able to tide you over until the Eclipse plugin comes out.  Who knows, you may even like NetBeans more.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using version 3.6.4 STS.  It works great.  Version STS 3.7.1 has been released but I have not tried it yet. 3.6.4 works great with Grails 2.4.4.  I have downloaded and installed Grails 3.0.9 and for my purposes it works just fine. Long time fan of Eclipse and I use it for UML, PHP, c++ and Java.

Comment: Grails STS is no longer being maintained