# Is there a way to install Grails support in Eclipse *without* installing STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, grails

I am looking for a plugin for Grails with Eclipse 3.8 but it seems for installing Grails support I have to install STS also. I really don't want to change my eclipse setup OR install the whole STS bundle just for getting grails support.

Anybody aware of any way to install just the Grails plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: [The Grails Eclipse plugin Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661020/grails-eclipse-plugin) has some interesting insights. I would gather that the simple answer is no, without STS integration the grails support would be very limited... why are you against it?

Comment: I have a version of eclipse configured with all the plugins I need(except the default ones). I *wish* the Grails support could also be installed just like another plugin and does not over bloat the IDE with other stuff(Core STS and so on). As far as I remember, I know there was a option to install just the grails support in any version of Eclipse without the need for STS, but not anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STS is effectively Eclipse with a few plugins and a few other minor changes thrown in (most notable the splash screen). I make this statement because I've used eclipse for 5 years now and I've recently been on a project for 2 months using STS and I don't see any major differences.

The reason we chose STS over standard eclipse was that download and installing all the plugins for Spring to work was a pain and Eclipse would just not work as expected. This was especially true with Maven support (effectively it wouldn't recognize my Spring web project as a web project). So STS was just the simpler solution though all the extra plugins etc make it slow.

You can get native [Groovy support for Eclipse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) and see if that is enough. Or else if you can afford to tinker, the STS Tools Install url is

> http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7

You can search for Grails there and install the support (**Disclaimer** I don't claim this works, all I'm saying is that you *can* do this since STS is basically Eclipse). It should also alert you to and install any dependencies you may need.

FYI, [IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 Community Edition (which is free) also supports Groovy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html) and as best I can tell from the documentation Grails.

**UPDATE**
As point out by OverZealous the free edition of IntelliJ IDEA does not support Grails framework.

Comment: The [free version of IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC) does **not** include Grails support.

Comment: I have used STS also, but right now I have a fresh Eclipse installation configured with a set of plugins and was looking for grails support only. I don't think that's possible now.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Grails plugin from the Eclipse Update link above?

Comment: @Ali: yes I did try to install the plugin using above URL, it automatically selects "Spring IDE Core" and "Spring Tools Suite" as part of dependencies.