# Grails...what's the latest IDE?

Tags: eclipse, grails, ide

Been out from the GRAILS-game for a while for various reasons.

What IDE is the best now? Before it was really a, b, c - deploy but it seems it's not as tied to Eclipse as it was...is STS still in the game?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661020/grails-eclipse-plugin/663883#663883

Comment: @billjamesdev that answer is 10 years old ;)

Comment: @lurker Well, originally, but it was updated a few times...

Comment: This question seems time dependent but it will remain relevant until someone picks up open source development of GGTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What IDE is the best now?

You aren't going to get a consensus answer to that.  IntelliJ IDEA is widely regarded as very good, and it is.  A data point is everyone on the core Grails team uses IntelliJ IDEA for Grails development.

> Before it was really a, b, c - deploy but it seems it's not as tied to
>   Eclipse as it was...

I don't know what that means.

> is STS still in the game?

No.  Groovy Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) was the extension to STS that added a bunch of Groovy and Grails tooling but that was pretty much moth-balled when we left Pivotal 5 years ago.  It is open source but no one has picked it up to run with it.

Comment: I was looking more for guidance rather than starting a battle on which one is the best. Your comment pushed me in the right direction - thanks will explore from here!

Comment: "I was looking more for guidance rather than starting a battle on which one is the best." - I don't think any battle is involved.